# How do you run a user-made Google Scripts function made in one spreadsheet in another spreadsheetmade

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

By the way, I specifically mean using a user-defined function made in one script inside of another, entirely different spreadsheet, inside of the spreadsheet itself. I already know how to use a function from one script inside of another script, but I do not know how to use said function in the actual spreadsheet itself.

My goal here is to create a 'master' script containing all user-defined functions to be used in any spreadsheet.

So if I made this script called 'TemplateScripts':

[image]

How could I use it like any other Google Sheets function in another spreadsheet? I hoped it would be the following, but it fails to work:

[image]

By the way, I have already done the necessary setup to use the functions from 'TemplateScripts' inside of the script file associated with the 'Ducks are Cute' spreadsheet, but can't use it as a function in the spreadsheet itself.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow please take this opportunity to take the [tour] and learn how to [ask], [format code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks), [mcve] and [Tag Info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info)

Comment: I am very interested in the answer, but couldn't find an answer yet.

Answer (score 1):

You dont use script editor name as a function. Put this above your script in scrip editor

```
/**
*@customfunction
*/
```

and use `=reverseCols(D1:F1)` in spreadsheet

Answer (score 0):

I have found a hack here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41287146/4970466. Basically do some reflection to inspect the current "this" context and retrieve the function given as parametrs. Not perfect, but at least it works.